# ArrayAdapter.getPosition(item) Returns What?

Tags: android, position, android-arrayadapter

I see the documentation says this method returns the position of the given item, but what would it return if no such item exists in the ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

After looking through the source code I've found that the ArrayAdapter uses  [`List.indexOf(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) to find the object and this method returns -1 when it doesn't exist.

GrepCode is awesome for finding stuff when the documentation is bad, I use it at least once a day :)

Source: [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.getPosition%28java.lang.Object%29)