# Xamarin.Android: item previously inserted in ArrayAdapter is not found again

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-arrayadapter

I've inherited this Xamarin.Android app and it has a few issues.

A particular bug involves an `ArrayAdapter<ProductListObject>`, where `ProductListObject` is a common POCO that's shared between subprojects (i.e. Android, Windows Phone and iOS); it just has a couple of properties (e.g. an `Id`) and overrides the (.NET) `Equals()` method to achieve structural equality:

```cs
public class ProductListObject
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is ProductListObject))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Id == (obj as ProductListObject).Id;
    }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I put an instance of this `ProductListObject` in an `ArrayAdapter`, I can't find it again, even if they have the same `Id`:

```cs
var p1 = new ProductListObject { Id = 1 };
var p2 = new ProductListObject { Id = 1 };

var areEqual = p1.Equals(p2); // returns True, as expected

var productAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ProductListObject>(this, 0, new[] { p1 });
var position = productAdapter.GetPosition(p2); // returns -1 >:(
```

My question is: what do I have to do to make my POCO's work with Xamarin.Android types that rely on the Java `equals()` method, internally ([like ArrayAdapter; which delegates to List.indexOf(Object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715222/arrayadapter-getpositionitem-returns-what))?

What I have tried:

- verified that the corresponding Java version works as expected (it does)
- overrode `GetHashCode()` (it doesn't matter, as I expected)
- googled and checked the Xamarin documentation for information about implementing `Equals()` (I found nothing particularly relevant)

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as Matt R suggested and created a proxy that inherits from `Java.Lang.Object` and delegates to the actual .NET object:

```cs
public class JavaObject<TValue> : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public readonly TValue Value;

    internal JavaObject(TValue value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(Java.Lang.Object that)
    {
        if (!(that is JavaObject<TValue>))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Value.Equals((that as JavaObject<TValue>).Value);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

This doesn't tie my platform-agnostic POCO's to the Android implementation, plus it doesn't force me to lock into some rigid inheritance tree, which is always a plus.

Application is straightforward:

```cs
var p1 = new JavaObject<ProductListObject>(new ProductListObject { Id = 1 });
var p2 = new JavaObject<ProductListObject>(new ProductListObject { Id = 1 });

var areEqual = p1.Equals(p2); // returns True, as expected

var productAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<JavaObject<ProductListObject>>(this, 0, new[] { p1 });
var position = productAdapter.GetPosition(p2); // returns 0!
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like .NET objects get wrapped within a `Java.Lang.Object` when used inside a `Android.Widget.ArrayAdapter`. Therefore, the comparison method that's used in the `productAdapter.GetPosition(...)` call is actually the java `Equals(Java.Lang.Object o)` method for the wrapping `Java.Lang.Object`.

To make a `ProductListObject` resolve to the same index when two objects have the same `Id`, make `ProductListObject` derive from `Java.Lang.Object`, override the `Equals(Java.Lang.Object)` and forward it to the .NET `Equals(System.Object)` method:

```
public class ProductListObject : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) // Inherited from System.Object.
    {
        if (!(obj is ProductListObject))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Id == (obj as ProductListObject).Id;
    }

    public override bool Equals (Java.Lang.Object o) // Inherited from Java.Lang.Object.
    {
        return this.Equals (o as System.Object);
    }
}
```

If you can't inherit `ProductListObject` from `Java.Lang.Object`, another option is to implement your own proxy class:

```
public class ProductListObject
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is ProductListObject))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Id == (obj as ProductListObject).Id;
    }
}

public class JavaProxy: Java.Lang.Object 
{
    public Object Object { get; private set; } 

    public JavaProxy(System.Object o)
    {
        Object = o;
    }

    public override bool Equals (Java.Lang.Object o)
    {
        var proxy = o as JavaProxy;
        if (o != null) {
            return Object.Equals (proxy.Object);
        }
        return base.Equals (o);
    }
}

// ...

var productAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<JavaProxy>(this, 0, new[] { new JavaProxy(p1) });
var position = productAdapter.GetPosition(new JavaProxy(p2));
```

It's not as clean as the first approach but it also works.

Comment: Yes, but that would tie my POCO's (which are used in Windows Phone and iOS subprojects too) to Xamarin.Android.

Comment: Is this a Xamarin.Forms app? If not, another option is to create your own `Java.Lang.Object` proxy that forwards its equals method to the .NET objects equals method.